# Meteor 1.3 Build pack for Heroku

Tags: javascript, meteor, heroku, npm

I'm in need of a working meteor buildpack for meteor 1.3 that works well on heroku. 
Any suggestions, ideas and or pointers would be much appreciated. Previous buildpack being used was https://github.com/seviu/heroku-buildpack-meteor which doesn't compile and install npm peer dependencies well on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having good luck with this:

https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git

Comment: thanks that really helped. Noticed https://github.com/seviu/heroku-buildpack-meteor is several forks leading to https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git with https://github.com/seviu/heroku-buildpack-meteor behind. Thanks again

Comment: No problem :) Would it be appropriate to mark as an answer?